# HDD randomly becomes read-only even after fsck

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, initramfs, fsck, read-only

I'm using a six year old notebook. The old HD died after it started to make some noises. The new one, after months of good use, started getting noisy too. However, the noise would stop for a whole day if i just restarted it twice before using it.

So yesterday, the screen freezes while using a lot of the processor, and  after the forced reboot, Ubuntu booted an `initramfs` terminal.

I ran `fsck /dev/sda1 -y` and Ubuntu booted normally, but the HD was read-only (and freezing for some seconds, which isn't common). After trying some solutions I figured out that the HD didn't boot read-only, it *became* read-only after using it for a while. Usually during downloads, such as updates, but i'm not quite sure what causes it to become read-only.

I'm not good with hardware, but i think this notebook might be a Hard-Drive killer.

***english screenshots :***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe, somewhere an overheading problem.  My old Notebook destroyed 3 hard drives untill  realized it.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the `Disks`application's SMART Data window. Also run the SMART Tests. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: anyone have translations for those photos? I know this sucks, but can you switch your system to english before taking the screen shots? thanks!

Comment: @heynnema , question updated. But the smart self-test failed.

Comment: It's sounds like the HDD is failing. I'll put together a quick answer and show you how to bad block the device, and maybe you can get a little more use out of it before it really becomes unusable.

Comment: @joshua Besneatte , english screenshots added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may, or may not, get a little more use out of the drive, before it fails entirely, by bad blocking it. You do not have a heat problem. You have 27 potentially bad blocks waiting to get remapped. Re-run the SMART diags after doing the bad blocking, to confirm status of the drive. A diags FAIL does not necessarily mean that the drive is unusable.

Understand that ultimately you'll probably have/want to replace the HDD. I recommend Western Digital drives, which is what you have now. You won't be able to purchase a 320G drive any more though.

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!
```

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Thanks. The `current pending sector count` has down from 26 to 22, after running your remcomended comand sucefully (and reboot the notebook twice). Is that the desired result ? Or there is something else i can do ?

Comment: @VitorOliveira Probably not. The effected potentially bad sectors may be in the area that's used for the SMART Diags... which I assume still fails, yes? Does the drive seem to operate any better/differently after the bad blocking? If not, it's time to replace it.

Comment: Yes, the SMART test still fails, and the drive is the same. Time to replace it then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it sounds like you may have a hardware issue. Likely the laptop is overheating. Try the following:

**1. Ensure you fan is working**

Do you hear the fan come on? Is it ALWAYS on? If it never comes on, you may need to replace your fan. If it's always on, your ducts might be clogged.

**2. Clean dust from cooling areas**

Try blowing out your fan ducts with compressed air. If you are comfortable doing so, open up the laptop and clean out the fan ducts with compressed air and a soft brush. Maybe even use a little rubbing alcohol.

**3. Boot from a live USB and fsck your HD from there**

You can also try booting from a live USB so that your HD is unused. You can now use disk utilities like `fsck` to really examine and treat your HD (although you probably were able to do the same in `intramfs` mode).

Comment: At 40 degrees C, it's not overheating.

Comment: perhaps the drive itself is not... could something else be getting too warm? could it be a poor HD to MB connection?

Comment: No, it's bad blocks on the HDD. Note the "Current Pending Sector Count" on the SMART Data screenshot.

Comment: Overheating might had been a problem until 5 moths ago, when i start using an cooler table. Before that, for arround 7 months, the temperature of almost everything was arround 70 degrees, according to Psensor. I don`t remember exactly the hd temperature tho.